# SQL GROUP BY month

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, reporting-services, group-by

See image.

In my report I need to have total Costs, Hours, Days for each 'ProjectName'

For some reason, I cannot get my view to Group all the data for each Project by Month, for example if you see July 2010 has 2 entries, I want this to be displayed as totals on one line. Can anyone help me.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Date_year, Date_month_number, Date_month_name, Service, Hours, Days, ProjectName, Cost
FROM         dbo.Resources_group_projectname
WHERE     (Service LIKE '%Housing%')
GROUP BY ProjectName, Date_year, Date_month_number, Date_month_name, Hours, Days, Cost, Service
ORDER BY Date_year, Date_month_number
```

[image]

Comment: Well your `GROUP BY` specifies other fields that keep the groups separate.  You need to explain some more about what you are after and how the grouping should work.

Comment: Images are much less useful than [sample code](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How do you want to combine/resolve the columns that are different like Hours, Days and Costs? Choose the MAX value? SUM them together?

Comment: Where I have ringed July 2010 there are 2 records. I want there to be 1 record which totals the Hours/Days and Cost and puts it in one record for that Project for that month

Comment: He has indicated that he wants totals for the month, so the solution seems fairly obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list of columns does not contain any aggregates. Try the following:

```
SELECT Date_year, Date_month_number, Date_month_name, Service, SUM(Hours), SUM(Days), ProjectName, SUM(Cost)
FROM dbo.Resources_group_projectname
WHERE (Service LIKE '%Housing%')
GROUP BY ProjectName, Date_year, Date_month_number, Date_month_name, Service
ORDER BY Date_year, Date_month_number
```

Comment: So i need to SUM Days, Hours and Cost?

Comment: Yes, you need to SUM those columns to get the total for the month.

Answer (score 1):

Your duplicates come about as your are grouping by more than just project and month, specifically by including hours and days.

You should therefore group by what you actually want as the key per line in your output, likely Project_Name, Date_Year and Date_Month_Number. Every other field you display should be an aggregate field, e.g. sum(hours)